# Can I configure PostgreSQL programmatically to not eliminate stop words in full-text search?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I'm using PostgreSQL full text search for a project where traditional stop words ('a', 'the', 'if' etc.) should be indexed and searchable, which is not the default behaviour. For example, I might want my users to find results for the query 'to be or not to be'.

The [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-dictionaries.html) indicates that I could achieve this by creating an empty stopwords dictionary in `$SHAREDIR/tsearch_data/english.stop` (for example), but this will complicate deployment; I want to be able to configure PostgreSQL's stop word handling with SQL. Is this possible? If so, can you provide a sample SQL statement?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

As per your comment on the previous answer, you can easily switch between using **no stop words** and **all stop words**.
You can acheive this with a custom search configuration:

(1) You can create a custom dictionary without using the stop words file, for example:

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY english_stem_nostop (
    Template = snowball
    , Language = english
);
```

Note, in the above I left out the **`StopWords`** parameter.

(2) Then create a new configuration to use your new dictionary:

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION public.english_nostop ( COPY = pg_catalog.english );
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION public.english_nostop
   ALTER MAPPING FOR asciiword, asciihword, hword_asciipart, hword, hword_part, word WITH english_stem_nostop;
```

(3)
Test new dictionary

```
select to_tsvector('english_nostop','he her the a');
```

Note that the response contains stop words. With ordinary dictionary response would be empty because second parameter contains only stop words.

(4) Then, when searching specify the config you want use (alternatively you can change the `default_text_search_config` option each time), eg:

```
SELECT
    title
FROM
    articles
WHERE
    to_tsvector('english_nostop', COALESCE(title,'') || ' ' || COALESCE(body,''))
    @@ to_tsquery('english_nostop', 'how & to');
```

You can specify just `'english'` in the above SQL to use the normal config.

***Note***, in this example that using the standard configuration will result in notices because there are only stop words.

---

Bear in mind the following, however:

- If you are using indexes, you will need two - one for each configuration. (see these docs: [tsearch tables](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/textsearch-tables.html) and [triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/textsearch-features.html#TEXTSEARCH-UPDATE-TRIGGERS)).
- Double check which parser tokens you want to use this mapping as per step #2, above (see [Parsers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/textsearch-parsers.html)).

Comment: Thanks, catchdave - that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

No, the stop words are only configurable through that file. You can have a server side function that modifies the file, but that requires the file to be write:able by the postgres service user, which you probably don't want.

Comment: OK, thanks. To be clear - it's not possible to tell PostgreSQL to not use *any* stopwords file?