# How to use to_tsvector with no-dictionary (no stemming)?

Tags: postgresql

I am using [`to_tsvector`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-controls.html), and it works fine... But a new demand, to preserve exact original words (raw text), need "bypass" as dictionary.

... something like to use `to_tsvector('raw', myString)` where `myString`  is something like "AATT GAA", no meaning for any dictionary.

Comment: `to_tsvector('simple', myString)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SELECT to_tsvector('simple','your string');`

Comment: Thanks @DanielVérité  and Dmitry.

Comment: Do you know how to exclude stop words in a certain language? No stemming but language-based stop words

Comment: If you want to avoid stopwords you could create a text search dictionary which simply used a blank file of stop words.  For instance, see link  for specifying a stopwords file in your dictionary.  Then you'll need to create a text search configuration that uses that dictionary.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/textsearch-dictionaries.html#TEXTSEARCH-STOPWORDS

Comment: Or better yet just directly skip them: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497895/can-i-configure-postgresql-programmatically-to-not-eliminate-stop-words-in-full

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else coming here is looking to *really* manually create a ts_vector you can skip using to_tsvector entierly (even with the simple dictionary it still sends it through the parser and drops spaces/punctuation e.g. ```to_tsvector('simple', '\Sigma^0_1') breaks that text up into three lexmes 0, 1 and sigma)

As described in this [part of the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/datatype-textsearch.html#DATATYPE-TSQUERY) and this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59687591/postgresql-is-it-possible-to-build-tsvector-value-manually). You simply do this

`$$' space containing lexeme ' ' and one with position and weight'5c$$::tsvector;`